# Taylor series exponential function $a^x$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can a Taylor series expansion be given for the function $(-2)^x$ about $x=0$? Perhaps, I couldn't find the value of the derivatives at the function at the point of consideration.

Comment: $(-2)^x$ is not a series. Also, the expression is not defined for $x<0$.

Comment: With a negative base, you run into trouble , already where $a^x$ is defined at all.